# Quantitative risk management strategy for a large participant in an illiquid market

Tags: risk-management, liquidity-risk

Are there any practical quantitative risk management strategies for a large participant  in an illiquid market with a few dominant players? By a large partcipant I mean someone who

- has significant share in the market turnover
- holds large inventory
- (therefore) could be a subject for predatory trading

By illiquid market I mean that trading is possible, however price impact is large and stealth liquidation of even a moderate position is not an option.

I'm currently looking for into a stress testing/scenario but may be there are better approaches?

Comment: What you are asking sounds like something most people like to keep to themselves. It is similar to someone asking for a VWAP strategy that can handle highly illiquid stocks that trade in a 3-5 tick range in a given trading day. It makes no difference whether it is an actual trading strategy or a risk management strategy. A successful approach presents and edge and I think most people like to keep an edge to themselves. Just my hunch.